# Css Image For Html.ActionLink

Tags: css, image, html.actionlink

```
 Html.ActionLink("", "ActionResult", new { CustomerId= DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "CustomerId") }, new { target = "_blank", @style = "background-image:url(/Image/edit.png); width:50px; height:30px;" }));
```

Hi,

I try to set image for actionlink however it is always empty.

How can i set image to html.actionlink ?

I want actionlink to appear like image(image button)

Note : Please do not offer me **a href** etc.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is `/Image/edit.png` a valid path?

Comment: Yes it is . Do you have another idea?

Comment: When loaded onto your page, if you inspect the element does it have these `style` properties attached?

Comment: As instance, If html.actionlink has expression(text) , image appears. if expression is null (" ") it does not appear.

Comment: Sounds like your element may be displaying as `inline`. What happens if you add `display:inline-block;` to the `@style` declaration?

Comment: James answer , i will accept your answer as correct.display:inline-block; works.

Comment: Ah brilliant! I've posted that as an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19687955/1317805 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, your image doesn't display when you aren't providing any text as your element is set to display as `inline`. With no text, your element has no size, regardless of any `width` or `height` properties that are specified in the element's style. To fix this, set the element to display as `inline-block`:

```
(Html.ActionLink(
    "",
    "ActionResult",
    new {
        CustomerId= DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "CustomerId")
    },
    new {
        target = "_blank",
        @style = "
            background-image:url(/Image/edit.png);
            display:inline-block;
            width:50px;
            height:30px;
        "
    })
);
```

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta ah rubbish! I only started doing that after seeing a tag with the tag markup within an excerpt; I never actually checked to see if that worked!

Answer (score 0):

I am using a hand made Html Helper I found on the net, here it is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Html helper that displays an image.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="_helper"></param>
/// <param name="_url"></param>
/// <param name="_altText"></param>
/// <param name="_clickMethod"></param>
/// <param name="_htmlAttributes"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static MvcHtmlString ImageClick(this HtmlHelper _helper, string _id, string _url, string _altText, string _clickMethod, object _htmlAttributes)
{
    TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("image");

    var path = _url.Split('?');

    string pathExtra = "";

    if (path.Length > 1)
    {
        pathExtra += "?" + path[1];
    }

    builder.Attributes.Add("src", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(path[0]) + pathExtra);
    builder.Attributes.Add("alt", _altText);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_clickMethod))
    {
        builder.Attributes.Add("onclick", _clickMethod + "()");
    }

    builder.GenerateId(_id);

    builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(_htmlAttributes));
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
}
```

Hope that will help!